# Able to go to login page even after been logged in

Tags: asp.net-core

I,m using the default Model-View-Controller template with Individual User Authentication enabled. The problem is when I've been logged in, I can still go to login page. How to prevent it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can customize a middleware to redirect when user logged in and access the login page.

**RedirectMiddleware.cs**

```
public class RedirectMiddleware
{
    private readonly RequestDelegate _next;

    public RedirectMiddleware(RequestDelegate next)
    {
        _next = next;
    }

    public async Task Invoke(HttpContext context)
    {
        if(context.Request.Path == "/Identity/Account/Login")
        {
            if (context.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
            {
                context.Response.Redirect("/Home/Index");
            }
        }
        await _next.Invoke(context);
    }
}
```

**Startup.cs**

```
app.UseMiddleware<RedirectMiddleware>();

app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
{
    endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
        name: "default",
        pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
    endpoints.MapRazorPages();
});
```

**Or**

Directly do the redirection in the Login OnGetAsync Handler:

```
public async Task OnGetAsync(string returnUrl = null)
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(ErrorMessage))
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, ErrorMessage);
        }
        if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            Response.Redirect("/Home/Index");
        }
        returnUrl = returnUrl ?? Url.Content("~/");

        // Clear the existing external cookie to ensure a clean login process
        await HttpContext.SignOutAsync(IdentityConstants.ExternalScheme);

        ExternalLogins = (await _signInManager.GetExternalAuthenticationSchemesAsync()).ToList();

        ReturnUrl = returnUrl;
    }
```

Comment: I implemented your answer. The problem is that IsAuthenticated method in RedirectMiddleware class is throwing false even after being authenticated.

Comment: @PrabeshUpreti Make sure `app.UseMiddleware<RedirectMiddleware>();` is after`app.UseAuthentication();`